Colcon build error in windows 10 ros2 Jazzy (may 2024) Edition
I am trying to install and run ROS 2 Jazzy on windows 10 latest update by following the long and uncomfortable nonsense steps as descried by the installation guide here "https://docs.ros.org/en/jazzy/Installation/Alternatives/Windows-Development-Setup.html"
after invoking the last install command "colcon build --merge-install" I face the following error:
"
warnings.warn(msg)
--- stderr: ament_clang_tidy
C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tests_require'
warnings.warn(msg)
Finished <<< ament_clang_tidy [12.3s]
Starting >>> ament_pclint
C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tests_require'
warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
warnings.warn(msg)
--- stderr: tinyxml2_vendor
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
Compatibility with CMake < 3.10 will be removed from a future version of
CMake.
Update the VERSION argument  value.  Or, use the ... syntax
to tell CMake that the project requires at least  but has been updated
to work with policies introduced by  or earlier.
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:233 (message):
Could NOT find TinyXML2 (missing: TINYXML2_LIBRARY TINYXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:603 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
cmake/Modules/FindTinyXML2.cmake:60 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

Failed   <<< tinyxml2_vendor [46.8s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< ament_pclint [5.01s]
Aborted  <<< eigen3_cmake_module [49.8s]
Aborted  <<< shared_queues_vendor [49.6s]
Aborted  <<< ament_cmake_vendor_package [3min 37s]
Aborted  <<< fastcdr [1min 7s]
Aborted  <<< iceoryx_posh [2min 3s]
Aborted  <<< foonathan_memory_vendor [4min 55s]
Summary: 63 packages finished [8min 18s]
1 package failed: tinyxml2_vendor
7 packages aborted: ament_cmake_vendor_package ament_pclint eigen3_cmake_module fastcdr foonathan_memory_vendor iceoryx_posh shared_queues_vendor
45 packages had stderr output: ament_clang_format ament_clang_tidy ament_cmake_clang_format ament_cmake_copyright ament_cmake_cppcheck ament_cmake_cpplint ament_cmake_flake8 ament_cmake_gen_version_h ament_cmake_lint_cmake ament_cmake_mypy ament_cmake_pep257 ament_cmake_xmllint ament_copyright ament_cppcheck ament_cpplint ament_flake8 ament_index_python ament_lint ament_lint_auto ament_lint_cmake ament_mypy ament_package ament_pep257 ament_pycodestyle ament_pyflakes ament_xmllint domain_coordinator eigen3_cmake_module gmock_vendor google_benchmark_vendor gtest_vendor launch launch_testing launch_xml launch_yaml osrf_pycommon osrf_testing_tools_cpp ros_environment rosidl_cli rpyutils shared_queues_vendor test_interface_files tinyxml2_vendor tracetools_read urdfdom_headers
293 packages not processed
WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT
TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)
"
my python version is 12. with the least pip updated version.
my cmake version is 3.30.1
I changed the required minimum version of cmake to be {version 10 ... 30}
the following is the stderr.txt  log file for   tinyxml_vendor package.
"CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
Compatibility with CMake < 3.10 will be removed from a future version of
CMake.
Update the VERSION argument  value.  Or, use the ... syntax
to tell CMake that the project requires at least  but has been updated
to work with policies introduced by  or earlier.
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:233 (message):
Could NOT find TinyXML2 (missing: TINYXML2_LIBRARY TINYXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:603 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
cmake/Modules/FindTinyXML2.cmake:60 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
"
and the stdout.txt loog file for the same package is
"-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30154.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30154.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found ament_cmake: 2.5.2 (C:/jazzy/install/share/ament_cmake/cmake)
-- Found Python3: C:/Python312/python.exe (found version "3.12.6") found components: Interpreter
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
"
-->
kindly guid me to solve this issue.
attached the loog files for other aborted 7 packages.
